# Return multiple files from fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

Using [fastapi](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi), I can't figure out how to send multiple files as a response. For example, to send a single file, I'll use something like this

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/image_from_id/")
async def image_from_id(image_id: int):

    # Get image from the database
    img = ...
    return Response(content=img, media_type="application/png")
```

However, I'm not sure what it looks like to send a list of images. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
@app.get("/images_from_ids/")
async def image_from_id(image_ids: List[int]):

    # Get a list of images from the database
    images = ...
    return Response(content=images, media_type="multipart/form-data")
```

However, this returns the error

```
    def render(self, content: typing.Any) -> bytes:
        if content is None:
            return b""
        if isinstance(content, bytes):
            return content
>       return content.encode(self.charset)
E       AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Not sure, but if `content` is a type of `List` then loop content: `for c in content: c.encode() ...`

Comment: @felipsmartins the objects in the list are bytes already, running `img.encode()` on them doesn't work `'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zipping is the best option that will have same results on all browsers. you can zip files dynamically.

```
import os
import zipfile
import StringIO


def zipfiles(filenames):
    zip_subdir = "archive"
    zip_filename = "%s.zip" % zip_subdir

    # Open StringIO to grab in-memory ZIP contents
    s = StringIO.StringIO()
    # The zip compressor
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")

    for fpath in filenames:
        # Calculate path for file in zip
        fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)
        zip_path = os.path.join(zip_subdir, fname)

        # Add file, at correct path
        zf.write(fpath, zip_path)

    # Must close zip for all contents to be written
    zf.close()

    # Grab ZIP file from in-memory, make response with correct MIME-type
    resp = Response(s.getvalue(), mimetype = "application/x-zip-compressed")
    # ..and correct content-disposition
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename

    return resp


@app.get("/image_from_id/")
async def image_from_id(image_id: int):

    # Get image from the database
    img = ...
    return zipfiles(img)
```

As alternative you can use base64 encoding to embed an (very small) image into json response. but i don't recommend it.

You can also use MIME/multipart but keep in mind that i was created for email messages and/or POST transmission to the HTTP server. It was never intended to be received and parsed on the client side of a HTTP transaction. Some browsers support it, some others don't. (so i think you shouldn't use this either)

Comment: Hi @kia, and thank you for the answer! Stack Overflow discourages single link answers (and it may get downvoted as a result). The answer would be improved if you could provide a small example that shows how to use `aiofiles` in this particular context.

Comment: Hi @Hooked and @kia, unless I'm missing something, zipping files as in your example is a blocking IO operation that might mess the asynchronous event loop under the hood. Consider either making a synchronous handler (remove the `async` in the definition of `image_for_id`, or consider running the `zipfiles` function under the control of a `TheadPoolExecutor` as in this example : https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Comment: @glenfant Can you please tell me why **"a blocking IO operation might mess the asynchronous event loop under the hood"**? thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I've got some problems with @kia's answer on Python3 and latest fastapi so here is a fix that I got working it includes BytesIO instead of Stringio, fixes for response attribute and removal of top level archive folder

```
import os
import zipfile
import io


def zipfiles(filenames):
    zip_filename = "archive.zip"

    s = io.BytesIO()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")

    for fpath in filenames:
        # Calculate path for file in zip
        fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)

        # Add file, at correct path
        zf.write(fpath, fname)

    # Must close zip for all contents to be written
    zf.close()

    # Grab ZIP file from in-memory, make response with correct MIME-type
    resp = Response(s.getvalue(), media_type="application/x-zip-compressed", headers={
        'Content-Disposition': f'attachment;filename={zip_filename}'
    })

    return resp

@app.get("/image_from_id/")
async def image_from_id(image_id: int):

    # Get image from the database
    img = ...
    return zipfiles(img)
```

Answer (score 11):

Furthermore, you can create the zip on-the-fly and stream it back to the user using a `StreamingResponse` object:

```
import os
import zipfile
import io
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

zip_subdir = "/some_local_path/of_files_to_compress"

def zipfile(filenames):
    zip_io = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_io, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as temp_zip:
        for fpath in filenames:
            # Calculate path for file in zip
            fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)
            zip_path = os.path.join(zip_subdir, fname)
            # Add file, at correct path
            temp_zip.write(fpath, zip_path)
    return StreamingResponse(
        iter([zip_io.getvalue()]), 
        media_type="application/x-zip-compressed", 
        headers = { "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename=images.zip"}
    )
```

Comment: please correct to `temp_zip.write(fpath, zip_path)`

Comment: also zip_subdir = "archive" here